# Docker run command, expose port private only

Tags: port, haproxy, docker, containers

```
docker run -it -p 8080 myimage /bin/bash
```

I would expect the code above to expose port 8080 private. However when I run:

```
docker ps -a
```

It shows:

```
0.0.0.0:32770->8080/tcp
```

How does one set port 8080 to expose only private?

Comment: what do you mean with private?

Comment: @c4f4t0r Not public. Internal networking! Not visible to the rest of the internet, only within the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that it is by default open within the host, so just removing the port flag from run was enough.

Bonus: You may map a port to the host directly via the flag `-p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080`