# Howto expose port in docker container

Tags: port, port-forwarding, docker, containers

I’ve run a web service in a docker container on a custom port (8080). Here, I’m trying to run a container, exposing the relevant container’s port (as [seen here](https://serverfault.com/questions/721820/docker-run-command-expose-port-private-only)), but the no avail.

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 beatthemarket run wait
```

But I can’t seem to reach that web service endpoint.

- http://127.0.0.1:8080
- http://localhost:8080

***i)*** Am I correctly exposing the container's port? ***ii)*** How can troubleshoot if it's the port that's unavailable, or if my web service just isn't getting called (it would be nice to be able to shell into the container and just curl the endpoint).

My Dockerfile can be seen [here](https://github.com/twashing/beatthemarket/blob/master/Dockerfile). And I’m using Adzerk’s [boot-clj](https://hub.docker.com/r/adzerk/boot-clj/) base image.

Actually running docker, each time retrieves a bunch of jars. Then [boot](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot) blocks (the `wait` task), which is what I want (a web server will be handling web requests). And this is where I’m lost. Boot, in docker, blocks as I’ve asked it to. But I can’t seem to get the basic **Hello World** message that a root URI [should return](https://github.com/twashing/beatthemarket/blob/master/src/beatthemarket/shell.clj#L12-L14).

```
$ docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 beatthemarket run wait
Downloading https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/releases/download/2.5.5/boot.jar...
Retrieving dynapath-0.2.3.jar from https://clojars.org/repo/
Retrieving pod-2.5.5.jar from https://clojars.org/repo/
Retrieving shimdandy-impl-1.2.0.jar from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
Retrieving core-2.5.5.jar from https://clojars.org/repo/
...
Implicit target dir is deprecated, please use the target task instead.
Set BOOT_EMIT_TARGET=no to disable implicit target dir.
```

The **Chrome**, curl and wget all say that the connection is refused.

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused

$ wget http://127.0.0.1:8080/
--2016-04-21 20:07:32--  http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080... failed: Connection refused.
```

Comment: You forgot to say what happens when you try to connect to the service.

Comment: Can you post the output of a `netstat -tunlp`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Absolutely. I've added docker output, and that nothing happens when trying to connect to the web service.

Comment: @prateek61, I'm on OSX, and when  I run `netstat -tunlp`, it tells me **netstat: option requires an argument -- p**.

Comment: Sorry, just do `netstat -tunl` for OSX

Comment: @prateek61 `netstat -tunl | wc` has over 500 lines. It takes too long to copy the entire thing. But the output looks [like this](http://pastebin.com/3gypz8Xg).

Comment: @Frye do you see 8080 listed in the output? Try grepping for it.

Comment: @pratheek61 No result. `netstat -tunl | grep 8080` returns empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `EXPOSE` statement to your Dockerfile for port 8080.

Here's the reference from Docker: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Your final Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM adzerk/boot-clj

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
```

Comment: After rebuilding the image, `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 beatthemarket run wait` still refuses a connection. According to the docs, running `docker run -P beatthemarket run wait` should ***Publish all exposed ports to the host interfaces***. But the connection also gets refused there as well... How do I shell into the container to sanity check that the web service started?

Comment: Update: I was able to shell into the container. And indeed the web server is up and responding to requests. So the issue is just that I can't access the container over HTTP.  Dockerfile [is here](https://github.com/twashing/beatthemarket/blob/master/Dockerfile). And I'm failing with both `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 beatthemarket run wait` and `docker run -P beatthemarket run wait` commands.

Comment: Try dropping the IP from the -p argument. Just use `-p 8080:8080`

Comment: Indeed. That solved my problem. Can now access the web service in the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

the -p switch will punch a hole through your host bridging to your docker instance, -p host_port:docker_instance_port

Now you have to find out where does your docker host reside. If you are using VirtualBox, try to run :

**docker-machine env**

http://javagoogleappspot.blogspot.com/2018/07/docker-basics.html